# How to float an image right so it stays right when window is resized?

Tags: qml, qtquick2

When I put an image in a rectangle, it's position is top-left. How can I anchor it top-right in a manner where it will remain there upon resizing the window?

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle {
    id: outestRec
    width: 500
    height: 500
    Image
    {
        id: imgLonnie
        source: "http://www.lonniebest.com/Image/Photo/LonnieLeeBest.png";
        //anchors.right: AnchorLine;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`anchors { right : outestRec.right; top: outestRec.top }`

Edit :

Explanation : To attach your element to the top, you have to use the top anchor. But just doing that wont be enough, as you have just specified that it should be attached to the top of parent, not exactly where. By just anchoring to the top, it is free to move anywhere horizontally. But attaching it to the right of parent will fix its position to the right top corner.

Only anchors.right : Attaches it to the right side, but still free to move up and down

Only anchors.top : Attaches it to the top , but still free to move left and right

Both together : There is only single possibility which satisfies both these conditions together, that is the right top corner.

Read [here in detail](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qml-anchor-layout.html).